# Query SQL Server logins or determine if login is admin on SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm modifying an application that was designed to work with SQL Server databases to work with  Azure SQL databases.

Most of the features and functions of the application appear to work well out of the box, or with minor tweaks but I've run into a snag with the following:

The application has an *administration* mode which allows a user to login using an account that has server admin rights and execute database updates when update patches are released. The application currently checks whether the user is in the `sysadmin` or `serveradmin` roles using the [IS_SRVROLEMEMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176015.aspx) function.

However, on the SQL Azure instance, this method always returns 0, regardless of the user context I execute it under.

So the question is, how can I determine if the current login is an Azure server administrator? Or get a list of the Azure administrator logins (or logins and their roles on the server)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess Azure database does not have server roles at all (it only has logins). Instead you should query master database for roles.

```
SELECT m.name as [Member]
, r.name as [Role]
FROM sys.database_role_members as drm
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals as m
    on drm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals as r
    on drm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
```

Make sure you execute it on master database. And remember you can not use "USE [dbname]" statement. "master" should be in your connection string.

[more on logins in azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/)

Answer (score 0):

server administrator permissions of Azure SQL Server and Azure SQL DW are not being reflected as database principals. instead, a logged-in admin user is the `dbo` user of the database. 
so, in order to identify if the user is `sysadmin` or `serveradmin` all you have to do is to query `SELECT current_user;` and compare the result to `dbo`.